# Run menu in gameloop or as activity?

Tags: java, android, optimization

Currently I am running my menu (with buttons "new game" and "choose level") as an xml view of an activity, that then starts my gameactivity with custom view run on a gameloop. But Im starting to see some restrictions with this.

Would it be a terrible idea to let the menu be part of the gameloop and just add another state for it, like `gameState = MENU` ? and then render and update touch accordingly.

Does anyone have any experience with this and if so how did you choose to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to set the menu in the game loop with your gameState = MENU.

Thus you won't have a waiting time between the moment when you have touched 'Play' and the moment when the game start.

As you said, separate menu from gameloop can bring some problems for the user experience.

You should use the game engine to render the Menu.

Comment: Yup, been thinking this for a while. Guess thats how Ill do it, and make a seperate thread to load resources. Thanks for ur advice

Comment: you can mark the question as answered :)